# The file '/ajax/namespace.class.GetSessionValue.ashx' does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have deployed an asp.net site in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and it works fine. However I wanted to debug some part of the code, copied the same folder to desktop and launched it through Visual studio using IIS express. Once the page loads it starts giving me a lot of error windows which have error description like below:

```
*Error Message: The file '/ajax/abc.cde.GetSessionValue.ashx' does not exist.
Stack Trace:    at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Source: System.Web
Inner Exception:*
```

I have changed the name `abc.cde.GetSessionValue.ashx` for safeguarding our code privacy. I have searched for this file through all the folder , subfolder of my code, it doesn't exist anywhere. Then question is how it just runs when I simply launch it from internet explorer and fails and pops up error when run through Visual studio?

Comment: You mentioned "deployed the asp.net site in C:\..." so how you deployed it? Did you publish the website into a folder?